# Javascript: User Authentication JSON Error

Tags: javascript, json, loops, object, authentication

I'm making a login page for my web application, and I'm using a temporary data storage (I know this is not safe) for user verifiation. I'm trying to compate the username input to the data (only correct email is needed at the moment to get it working), but it's not working at all. I'm not getting an error message, just the alert that the username is not correct. It now displays both the user input and data, so I can see that my input is correct. What's wrong with it?
Thanks in advance!
(The data/object is in a seperate js file)

```
var count = 2;
function validate() {
var un = document.login.username.value; /* Username Input variable*/
var pw = document.login.password.value; /* Password Input variable*/
var valid = false;

let data = responseData;
for(var account in data.accounts){
    if( un == account.responseData.authenticatUser.RSP.USR.CONT.EML){
        var valid = true;
        console.log("Yes");
        break;
    }
}
if (valid) {
    alert("Login was successful. Welcome, " + un + ".")
    window.location = "https://www.google.com";
    return false;
}

if (count >= 1) {
    alert("The correct username is " + item_name + ", you put in "+un);
    count--;
}

var responseData = {
authenticatUser: {  
   "ERR":0,
   "RSP":{  
      "AUTHC":"true",
      "USR":{  
         "ID":"2",
         "TJT":"FULL",
         "ACTV":"true",
         "BO":"1489760664786",
         "CONT":{  
            "FNM":"John",
            "LNM":"Doe",
            "PHN":"5556667777",
            "PHNTP":"NONE",
            "EML":"ex@mple.com",
            "EMLTP":"NONE"
         },
         "ADMIN":"false",
         "LLOGN":"1489760664786",
         "ACCT":{  
            "ID":"2",
            "TJT":"ID"
         }
      }
   }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
if( un == account.responseData.authenticatUser.RSP.USR.CONT.EML){
    var valid = true;
```

You are initializing a new `valid` variable that is only seen in that function. When you later access it outside the function you are seeing the original `valid` you initialized in line 5. This is called shadowing and it's a common source of bugs.

Do this instead:

```
if( un == account.responseData.authenticatUser.RSP.USR.CONT.EML){
    valid = true;
```

Now you should be changing the original `valid` variable.

Comment: It didn't change anything, the bug is still there. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is you `console.log("yes")` printing?

Comment: No, it did not print anything.

Comment: Hmm, it also looks like your data access is messed up a bit. You have an object `responseData` with one top-level key: `authenticatUser`. But in your code you are treating 'responseData` like an array of `account` objects. When you try to iterate over these nonexistent `accounts` it won't find anything.

Comment: It had to do with my data access, thank you! It's solved now.